# No overload for method 'TranslateAsync' takes 4 arguments for Bing Transaltor

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, localization, language-translation, microsoft-translator

working on an old translation sample code for windows phone 7.

Recently, I have downloaded the LanguageServiceClient or translator Api from this
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Soap.svc in my project.

I notice there is a change in the method for TranslateAsync

use this old method calling this method in my page

```
_proxy.TranslateAsync(APP_ID, txtInput.Text, from.Code, to.Code);
```

This throw error message:

> No overload for method 'TranslateAsync' takes 4 arguments

I discovered in the old sample code, it has:

Old Signature Existed in Old Sample Code:

```
public void TranslateAsync(string appId, string text, string from, string to) {
    this.TranslateAsync(appId, text, from, to, null);
```

BUT the new signature in this RECENT Translator api is this :

```
 public void TranslateAsync(string appId, string text, string from, string to, string contentType, string category) {
     this.TranslateAsync(appId, text, from, to, contentType, category, null);
 }
```

How Do I use this New Signature? What are contentTye, category ? Where can I get these info or sample code that use these?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer center for the Microsoft Translator service is here: http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/ which gives the documentation being located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512423.aspx. The documentation for the [`Translate` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512437.aspx) indicates that the **contentType** parameter is used to specify the format of the supplied content and accepts the values **"text/plain"** or **"text/html"**. If you specify HTML, then the HTML must be well-formed. The **category** parameter supports a single value: **general**.

Comment: Thank Q. My code now working. This is the piece of info that I need for the new method.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you may find it easier to use the REST api for the translation service instead of the SOAP service - this API is very easy to call using either direct HTTPWebRequest's or using a REST client library like Hammock.

I've used this API in this ruby script http://script.iron7.com/#/Script/Detail?scriptId=46ea32cd1aa4436fa7089d70722f7de8&userLowerCaseName=stuart (and again in the app http://www.wp7comp.com/translate-a-bull-get-multilingual-get-bovine/)

I found it easier to code against the raw HTTP REST rather than against the generated SOAP - e.g. a Translate is:

```
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate?appId=YOUR_KEY&from=from+lang&to=to+lang&text=what+you+want+to+translate
```

Comment: @ Stuart: Will try out this REST. Sound interesting. Will check out the documentation.